# The handling of exceptions uses the browser instead of the exception assistant

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am working with MVC4. 
When I cause an exception the information is shown in the browser.
How can I get the exception information in an exception assistant instead?
Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. If I may try to explain: When I run a console application and I get an exception, the exception assistant pops up and I can edit variables and continue. Now I only get the browser to popup with the exception message and it does not let me continue

Comment: I tried:<CustomErrors mode="Off">  but it does not seem to change things....

Answer (score 0):

You can use Exception Handling in Global.asax:

```
 protected void Application_OnError( )
    {
        var exception = Server.GetLastError( );
         //handle exception here
    }
```

You can also use Exception filters:

There is a method 'RegisterGlobalFilters()' having 'filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute())' filter that **deals with all the errors** in MVC application. The method 'RegisterGlobalFilters()' called by 'Application_Start()' method.

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFiltersCollection filters)
{
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
}
```

Error View

The Error view that is created by default contains the following HTML:

```
 Collapse | Copy Code
@{
   Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
   <title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h2>
       Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request.
   </h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Accessing the exception details in Error view:

```
public class HandleErrorInfo
{   
    public HandleErrorInfo(Exception exception, string controllerName, 
        string actionName);

    public string ActionName { get; }

    public string ControllerName { get; }

    public Exception Exception { get; }
}
```

Check this link for further information :

[Exception Handling in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/422572/Exception-Handling-in-ASP-NET-MVC#handleerror)

**PD:**

Set in web.Config:

```
<CustomErrors mode="Off">
```

to stop watching the exception in browser

Answer (score 0):

Create an Error Controller with several methods (each method is an error) :

```
public Class Error : Controller 
{
   public ActionResult ErrorMethodName()
   {
      return View();
   }
}
```

In each ErrorName.cshtml, write informations about your error.

Now for each Method in your other Controllers do this :

```
   public ActionResult MethodeName()
   {
      try
      {
         // your code
      }
      catch (exception)
      {
         return.RedirectToAction('ErrorMethodName','Error');
      }
   }
```

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. If I may try to explain: When I run a console application and I get an exception, the exception assistant pops up and I can edit variables and continue. Now I only get the browser to popup with the exception message and it does not let me continue ....